# Docker: I'm not able to make working a volume binding at runtime

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm executing my image in this way:

```
docker run -it --rm my_image -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/realtebo/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
```

So I expect that my private rsa key is copied at runtime when executing.

This is the shell script I used as entrypoint

```
pwd
ls -la ~/.ssh
```

At runtime I got this

```
/home/realtebo
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 realtebo realtebo 4096 Jan 19 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 realtebo realtebo 4096 Jan 19 08:37 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 realtebo realtebo  393 Jan 19 08:20 known_hosts
```

So the working dir and the user are ok.

> note: known_hosts is created at build time

**Why cannot I get `/home/realtebo/.ssh/id_rsa` as I expect ?**

I do some debugging using `docker inspect <container_name`. I discovered that :

```
"HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
 ....
```

But what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: exchange `-v` flag and image_name. 
Image name must always be the last argument (followed by optional cmd to execute)

So instead of

```
docker run -it --rm my_image -v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/realtebo/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
```

I need to execute in this way:

```
docker run -it --rm v ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/realtebo/.ssh/id_rsa:ro my_image
```